# nested virtualization: shutting down L2 kills L1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am looking to run an Linux VM (L2) within a GCE Ubuntu instance (L1). I am following the steps described at:

[Nested Virtualization on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances)

Everything works just fine until I shut down or terminate the L2 instance. Once the L2 instance is shut down, the L1 goes into a kernel panic. Has anyone seen this? Any ideas?

I tried exactly the same thing on Microsoft Azure, and it works just fine.

Thanks,

-ujwal

Comment: You should find a way to summarize the steps you are following in your question, rather than linking to an external resource.

Comment: OK. 1. Build an image with nested virtualization enabled: gcloud compute images create nested-vm-image \
  --source-disk disk1 --source-disk-zone us-central1-a \
  --licenses "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx" 2. Launch 3. SSH 4. Install kvm: sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm -y 5. Download an image for the L2 VM: wget https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/amd64/debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2 6. Launch L2: sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -hda debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2 -m 512 -curses 7. Shutdown L2: /sbin/shutdown -h now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should exit the nested VM as mentioned in the same docs "by hitting the Ctrl + a, Ctrl + d buttons".

I additionally tested it on a Debian 9 L1 instance and it worked as a charm. It supports the /sbin/shutdown -h now command. Maybe this is related to the image version you are running in the L1 instance.

Finally, you should notice this feature is still in beta.

Comment: Ctrl+a, Ctrl+d does not shutdown the L2 VM. It just disconnects from the screen session. I want to terminate the L2 VM after I am done with it. I used Ubuntu 16.04 as my base L1 VM. I will try Debian and CentOS and Fedora. I know this is beta, but something as basic as a clean shutdown should work IMHO.

Comment: @cryotex, Using Debian 9 as the L1 base VM worked like a charm. Using Ubuntu 16.04, I run into this issue. Wonder if a bug got introduced into the kvm kernel module later on? Will try centos and fedora as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: There is clearly an issue with newer kernels for nested virtualization on GCP.  I tried both Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.13) and Fedora 27 (4.15) as both the L1 and L2 VMs.  Whenever a newer kernel is involved, that kernel dies.  If I launch L2 Ubuntu/Fedora on L1 Debian, L2 Ubuntu/Fedore dies.  If I launch L2 Debian on L1 Ubuntu/Fedora, L1 Ubuntu/Fedora dies.  If I launch L1 Ubuntu/Fedora on L2 Ubuntu/Fedora, then It's a race to which one dies :)

Comment: I think this is a bigger problem than the initial problem report. Should I open a new issue?

Comment: @UjwalSetlur, nice investigation work here. For future reference, you can file Compute Engine issues using our external issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=0. We have a fix in hand that will roll out with our next host kernel and we are investigating other, shorter-term mitigations. If you file an issue per above, I can provide updates on it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ScottVanWoudenberg, awesome! I will open an issue on the issue tracker. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottVanWoudenberg, issue created: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/73717909